# mongodb update multiple keys inside sub document

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to update more than one keys inside a subdocument at once (within the given subdoc _id) instead writing the query like that:

```
articles.updateOne(
    {
        _id: 123,
        'data._id': 5,
    },
    {
        $set: {
            'data.$.comments': 10,
            'data.$.visible': true,
        },
    },
);
```

Sample document:

```
{
    "_id" : 123,
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : 5
            "comments" : 8,
            "visible" : false,
            "status" : null,
        }
    ]
}
```

I am looking for such a solution:

```
        $set: {
            'data.$': { visible: true, comments: 10 },
        },
```

... in other words: Is it able to submit a object with a few keys to update only the given keys inside the object and leave the existing keys untouched? Like MySQL... `UPDATE * ... SET foo = 'bar', test = 'hello', ...`

Comment: no, when you assign object it will replace full object, the only way that you used in first query.